Are Stack Snippets always safe to run?
Whenever I see a code snippet, I feel like it is not always safe to run something I don't know in a website. It might contain malicious code or execute something I don't want.
So, I would like to know for sure if it is designed to always be safe for the client or it is not guaranteed. So, I can behave accordingly in the future.

Well nothing is "always safe" when it comes to IT, there is no such thing as absolute security. AFAIK they do run in a sandbox on top of the sandbox that modern browsers do create on their own though.

It's the web. Do you feel safe loading pages with JS enabled?

@yivi it's not quite that simple? I think this is a pretty valid question.

Consider reading the code and attempting to understand what it does before running it...

No, not yet.
First, we need RFC 3514 to be adopted that would require evil doers on the internet to set the evil bit in IPv4 packets to signify they are evil.
RFC 3514 is not a technical requirement but it will pave the way for a similar feature being introduced in JavaScript, CSS, and HTML that would allow (and require) programmers submitting evil code to mark their code as such.
Then we can have guarantee snippet safety.
Right now anybody can run almost any code in one. It might be as unsophisticated as a while(true); infinite loop which will lock up the browser. Or something more sophisticated like making your machine mine cryptocurrency. Or show you a message using plain HTML requiring you to transfer money to somebody. Or have some visually unpleasant styling with CSS to attack your vision.
The snippets are sandboxed but overall that is not a complete solution for safety. It does at least mean that a snippet cannot do stuff like alter the page you are looking at (e.g., change all links to go to a different site, or even redirect you to it). Whether that is adequate or not is up to you to decide.

A more useful interpretation of this question might be "is running a Stack Snippet capable of performing any unsafe action that could not be accomplished by getting the user to click a link?"
